# How can I set a height for my tbody, because I have a footer and header on every printed page

Tags: css, laravel, printing, media-queries, yield

I'm using @media css for printed pages on html...

I have a footer and a header coming from the database, and my content too. 
And I don't know how much content comes. To output my content I'm using @yield from Laravel, and my content exceeds the fixed footer

This is the HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">{!! (!empty($headerFooter->header)) ? $headerFooter->header : '' !!}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="icon-bar-chart theme-font hide"></i>
                 <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase">{{ $title }}</span>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase">{{ $printDate }}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                @yield('content')
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <br>

            <td>
                {!! (!empty($headerFooter->footer)) ? $headerFooter->footer : '' !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    page-break-inside: auto;
}

table th {
    border: none !important;
}

@media print {
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

    tfoot {
        height: 100px;
        display: table-footer-group;
        position: fixed; bottom: 0;
    }
}

table td.content, .content .row {
    width: 100% !important;
}

@page
{
size: auto;

margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
}
```